# Tagging games with numbers as series

Tags: discussion, tags, numbers

Do we want to be consistent with numbering in our tags? There's generally two conventions, your standard 0-9, and roman numerals (i, ii, etc), and we're already using both. It seemed harmless at first, until I thought about games we haven't covered yet that would be numbered, and I saw...

`[megaman-x]`

Many people unfamiliar with the timeline confused Megaman X as being the "10th game in the series" rather than a separate series altogether. Now that we actually have a 10 to stifle that confusion, it's understood that X would refer to the actual letter, not the number.

Further research shows that I'm actually bad at memory and the first 6 games weren't numbered with roman numerals. However, the 5 games on the Game Boy *were*. Which means there's literally bother a [megaman-5] and a [megaman-v]. So it's really a confusing if you don't actually know the series to know that they're separate games.

In review, the majority of game tags we currently have do use 0-9, it's only a small handful that use roman numerals. Do we think it's a good idea we solidify the 0-9 system for numbering the different games in a specific series? Or maybe we really should just stick with how it is rendered in the actual game title, even if it can be confusing?

Comment: Tagging the Mario series might be more a challenge. Do you tag the New Super Mario Bros. Wii as `[new-super-mario-bros] [wii]` or `[new-super-mario-bros-wii]` ? :)

Comment: I would say the second because that's actually the game's name. Although, you might want to put the Wii tag on anyway.

Comment: Related, for focus on the 'series' aspect rather than the 'numeric': http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-should-sequels-game-series-be-tagged

Comment: @Adam: actually, i would go for `[new-super-mario-bros-wii]` `[wii]` and `[new-super-mario-bros]` `[ds]`, to prevent confusion, since the short name is also a valid game name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12181/4797) (a more recent community consensus on the same topic) | Related: [Platform Tags are Useless](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4638/4797)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My thought, using your specific megaman example (which seems to be a good example), is to not use roman numerals ever, and to provide a console context when needed, and you should be able to distinguish between all of these. So the three games you mentioned would be:

```
[megaman-5] [gameboy]
[megaman-5] [nes]
[megaman-x]
```

(Note: [snes] tag is not actually needed on Megaman X, but might be nice for a console spanning series like that)

Comment: I agree, sticking with plain numbers is probably the best idea.

Comment: I think what Adam is getting at is that there is both a Megaman X and a Megaman 10 and they are two different games.

Comment: @tzenes Megaman 5 and Megaman V are also 2 completely different games. However, in this situation, V actually stands for 5, while X does not stand for 10.

Comment: @Grace I've been calling those Megaman World, as the original name was Rockman World V, where as Megaman 5 was just Rockman 5.

Comment: @tzenes I'm really happy to see someone who actually knows that name, and consequently someone who knows that game. I suppose once we run into those, we'll have to discuss whether we want to use "world" in the tags or not, or if we can get away with just the system tag (since it's very apparent what [megaman-5] [gameboy] will be about).

Comment: @Grace this is going to date me a little, but I used to import the Rockman games, so to me the blue man will always be Rockman.  Roll also makes more sense that way. As do Treble and Bass

Comment: Your discussions makes me wonder, how would the Final Fantasy series be tagged.  I mean, is it [final-fantasy-6] (Japan) or [final-fantasy-3] (US)?

Comment: I think that by this point in time, every US gamer accepts that it is 4/6. The re-releases, after all, got the proper numbering, and now that the actual 2 and 3 have come stateside, I don't think there will be much confusion. Trying to use the old numbers will just be confusing people.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe it's best to use the actual name of the game. For example, there is no game called "Diablo 2", but there is one called "Diablo II".

But then again, not everyone knows (or cares about) the correct game name...

**EDIT** I'm keeping my answer here for historical purposes but I do like to say I prefer Adam's solution better after all.

Answer (score 2):

Creating synonyms for the games released with roman numerals (and a search that picks it up) might be a solution, so that `[final-fantasy-7]` automatically becomes `[final-fantasy-vii]`.

This solution also allows the mega-man games to co-exits under their proper name, by not creating a synonym where applicable.

[also here...](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/662/add-search-capability-for-roman-numerals/694#694)

BTW: the Mega Man Series are [annoying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mega_Man_games) anyways ;)

Answer (score 0):

What is the situation here? Megaman aside, nobody seems to have disagreed with alexanderpas and Oak's answers, but we're not acting on those suggestions. The most notable example, somewhat inevitably, is [starcraft-2].

Comment: The situation is undecided. No one has disagreed with Oak or alex directly on using the official numbering; nor has anyone disagreed with myself and Adam who say we should stick with 0-9 only. This is why I haven't, for example, gone and made synonyms for all of the Final Fantasy games to point at the other numbering system.

Comment: I'm sorry, where do either of you say that? To be clear, I'm talking about in general and not any specific edge case. Isn't the "use accurate names" suggestion in direct disagreement with yours? @Grace

Comment: Very first sentence of Adam's answer says "not use roman numerals ever". I agree, mostly on the grounds that I think it looks better for consistency in all tags (in the same vein that we use US English spellings) to use the same numbering scheme. And while our approaches are opposed, neither side is really saying that the other is a bad idea. Which is the crux of why this situation is undecided.