# How should sequels / game series be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

If there are multiple games in a series that share a common name, how should these be tagged?

Take [How do I lower my weapon in Halo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/681/how-do-i-lower-my-weapon-in-halo-3) for example.

Should this be tagged:

- **halo-3** only, as it refers only to Halo 3?
- **halo** and **halo-3**, to allow all Halo questions to be found under one tag? (With **halo-1** or **combat-evolved** to differentiate from the original?)
- Something else?

Comment: Related, but not duplicate: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tagging-games-with-numbers-as-series

Comment: I think the problem in this question is with games where the first game is also the name of the series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is analogous to how the other sites treat Windows questions for example.

- **windows** for generic questions
- **windows-xp**, **windows-vista**, **windows-7**, etc for specific versions.

so your first example would be the way.

You can specify wildcards in your interesting tags so "halo*" would find all questions tagged "halo", "halo-2", "halo-combat-evolved" etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following:

- What is Samus backstory? `[metroid-series]`
- What hapens when you get 100% completion on metroid? `[metroid]` `[nes]`
- How to beat the last boss in metroid prime 3? `[metroid-prime-corruption]` `[wii]` `[spoiler]`

Using the series (or even universe) addition will prevent confusion, when the first game has the same name as the series or the respective universe (`[half-life]` anyone?)

Answer (score 0):

I would use as follows:

Question: What is Master Chief's backstory? Tag: `halo`

Question: How do I get the recon armor? Tag: `halo-3`

I don't think it's ever necessary to use both for one question.

Answer (score 0):

If the consensus lies with ChrisF, we need to do more to retain consistency. [Lots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft+starcraft-2) of StarCraft II questions are being tagged [starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) *and* [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2).

Edit: Hopefully I've fixed this specific problem correctly. StarCraft I questions are currently tagged [starcraft], whereas I think [starcraft-1]/[starcraft-i]* would be more appropriate. I won't change all those questions without the thoughts of others though.

*Related issue: [Tagging games with numbers as series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tagging-games-with-numbers-as-series)