# Should Bioshock Infinite be considered part of the series?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

My [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96475/how-is-american-exceptionalism-shown-throughout-the-bioshock-titles) was retagged from [bioshock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock)[bioshock2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock2)[bioshock-inifinite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-inifinite) to [bioshock-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-series).

what I would have considered a series, is Bioshock 1 and 2 would be the series/sequels. while, Bioshock Infinite would be a completely new series of games for Irrational Games.

I looked at quite a few related questions

[How should we be tagging questions about multiple games in a series?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4003/how-should-we-be-tagging-questions-about-multiple-games-in-a-series)

[Reconsidering how we tag games in a series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/reconsidering-how-we-tag-games-in-a-series)

[How should sequels / game series be tagged?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-should-sequels-game-series-be-tagged)

[Tagging games with numbers as series](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tagging-games-with-numbers-as-series)

From my understanding of Bioshock Infinite, is that it is only related to the other games through a central theme and name. That, Bioshock Infinite, isn't an addition to the series or sequel more of a new series entirely.

So, should Bioshock Infinite be included in the [bioshock-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bioshock-series)

Comment: I'd consider them the same series. At the end of the day, you've still got plasmids.

Comment: The fact that you're asking about all three games in your question inclines me to agree that they're games in a series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel that, in the case of your linked question, it should apply, yes. The question's primary thrust is about all of the games as a whole, and thus applies succinctly to an overarching tag about... all of the games as a whole.

Final Fantasy V and IX really have nothing in common aside from the common name and series, but a question that discussed them as part of a larger pan-series query would, in fact, be tagged [final-fantasy-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-series).

Comment: yah, in relation to FF it makes sense.