# Add search capability for roman numerals

Tags: feature-request, numbers

Please add numeric-conversion capability to the search mechanism. Tons of games have sequels that are either written as VII or 7. Case in point: I posted [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/ffvii-re-release) because I didn't see [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3007/will-there-ever-be-a-ff7-remake) when I was typing the question and leafing through the related questions. Can patterns that match roman numerals be translated to numerals and added to the search? It might be a little rarer, but numbers could be translated as well and added to the search, so that FF7 matches posts for FFVII.

Answer (score 4):

A solution would be to extensively use the tag synonyms for the games that use roman numerals and do not have a game known under the normal numerals.

Examples:

- `[final-fantasy-7]` -> `[final-fantasy-vii]`
- `[megaman-v]` seperate
- `[megaman-5]` seperate
- `[mega-man-X]` seperate
- `[mega-man-10]` seperate

Answer (score 3):

The tags page allows character-by-character incremental search. It should cover all your prefixation needs.

Answer (score 1):

The point was made that some Megaman games are numbered 1, 2, 3 and some are numbered I, II, III. ([reference](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tagging-games-with-numbers-as-series))

And what happens if/when we get a medical SE and somebody performs a search for IV (intravenous) catheters? They'll get a bunch of unrelated questions that happen to have a '4' in their bodies.