# Tag synonym request: [street-fighter-4] [street-fighter-iv]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Since [street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-4) and [street-fighter-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-iv) are the same game…

I'm not sure about the direction, though. [street-fighter-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-iv) is the game's official title, but [street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-4) has more questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tag synonym request: Street Fighter tags](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14638/tag-synonym-request-street-fighter-tags) (more recent community consensus on how to write this game's tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was decided [early on](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tagging-games-with-numbers-as-series/180#180) that we should stick to non-roman numerals for games as a general site consistency - this way, users don't have to concern themselves about trying to remember whether it is a roman numeral or not.

Tag synonyms make that reasoning a bit moot now, but I don't see as much reason to break the habit now. Direction of [street-fighter-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-iv) → [street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-4). Remember, this can be easily swapped at any point.

Comment: I don't see the reason. Roman numerals must be upper case. Tags must be lower case. I'd rather have numbers than lowercase roman numerals.

Comment: Could I request confirmation that we are still sticking to this? I have since been told "no"