# Mass Roman -> Arabic numeral retag request

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Early in the site's life, we decided that we would use [Arabic numerals rather than Roman numerals](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164/tagging-games-with-numbers-as-series) for tagging games with numbers in their titles (i.e. [final-fantasy-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7) rather than [final-fantasy-vii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-vii)). A recent example of discussion on enforcement of this policy would be [this discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/tag-synonym-request-street-fighter-4-street-fighter-iv) from June on retagging Street Fighter 4.

While searching for questions regarding Final Fantasy 13, I noticed its tag had apparently slipped through the cracks, as had a few others. I can't just suggest synonyms for the current tags because, according to policy, the Arabic numeral versions of the titles should be made the parent tag and the Roman numeral versions should be made the synonym.

So far I've found that we have:

- [caesar-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar-iii), should be [caesar-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caesar-3), 1 question
- [europa-universalis-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europa-universalis-iii), should be [europa-universalis-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europa-universalis-3), 2 questions

  ### Heroes of Might and Magic series
- [heroes-might-magic-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-iii), should be [heroes-might-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-3), 3 questions
- [heroes-might-magic-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-iv), should be [heroes-might-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-4), 1 question
- [heroes-might-magic-v](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-v), should be [heroes-might-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-5), 3 questions
- [heroes-might-magic-vi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-vi), should be [heroes-might-magic-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-6), 1 question

  ### Final Fantasy series
- [final-fantasy-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-iii), should be [final-fantasy-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-3), 1 question
- [final-fantasy-vi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-vi), should be [final-fantasy-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-6), 1 question
- [final-fantasy-vii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-vii), should be [final-fantasy-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-7), 25 questions
- [final-fantasy-viii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-viii), should be [final-fantasy-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-8), 3 questions
- [final-fantasy-ix](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-ix), should be [final-fantasy-9](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-9), 2 questions
- [final-fantasy-x](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-x), should be [final-fantasy-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-10), 6 questions
- [final-fantasy-xi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xi), should be [final-fantasy-11](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-11), 2 questions
- [final-fantasy-xii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xii), should be [final-fantasy-12](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-12), 1 question
- [final-fantasy-xiii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiii), should be [final-fantasy-13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-13), 18 questions
- [final-fantasy-xiv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-xiv), should be [final-fantasy-14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-14), 4 questions

I am unable to search for any instances of I or V in names because they're single characters, so if those are floating out there still, I've missed them.

Comment: I was just gonna ask about the same thing! :D

Comment: ...how about Final Fantasy X-2, which IIRC isn't Final Fantasy 12?

Comment: @badp That's the sequel to Final Fantasy 10, so it's commonly referred to as Final Fantasy 10-2. We'll have the same situation with the upcoming sequel to Final Fantasy 13, which will have to be Final Fantasy 13-2.

Comment: ...ugh. That's a pretty damn horrible naming scheme

Comment: Gross.  Do we at least have synonyms with the Roman numerals?  **Edit:** Ah, awesome, my bad!

Comment: @Matthew Yes, click badp's link in his answer.

Comment: @badp Yeeeeah I know. Squeenix's storytelling methods are a little... uh. Insane. *peers at Kingdom Hearts*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12181/4797) (a more recent community consensus on the same topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Done!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest)

Comment: It might be a good idea to preemptively synonymize tags for other versions that haven't been asked about yet if possible.  That way it doesn't have to be revisited again when the time comes.