# Change [heroes-might-magic-6] -> [might-magic-heroes-6]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

With the new title of the Heroes of Might and Magic series, they have re-titled the game (and all future games) to "Might and Magic Heroes: VI". I propose the tags [heroes-might-magic-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-6) and [heroes-might-magic-vi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-vi) be changed to reflect this, with perhaps the current tags as tag synonyms for the new tag.

Comment: They should definitely be synonyms of each other, I'm not sure which one should be primary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary tag is now the one shown on the box art - [might-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-6) (keep in mind our [roman numbers policy](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/mass-roman-arabic-numeral-retag-request)). Yes, there's also a synonym from [might-magic-heroes-vi](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-vi).