# Might & Magic tag cleanup request

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't really know much about this game or the series, but the tags for *Might and Magic* seem to be all over the place.  Can someone familiar with it suggest what they should be and  some mod rename?

- [heroes-might-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-3)
- [heroes-might-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-4)
- [heroes-might-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-5)
- [might-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-6)
- [might-and-magic-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-and-magic-7)

***Related:***
[Change [heroes-might-magic-6] -> [might-magic-heroes-6]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/change-heroes-might-magic-6-might-magic-heroes-6)

Comment: There are two series of games here. [Heroes of Might & Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic) (a turn based strategy game) and [Might & Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Might_and_Magic) (a turned based RPG). It might help if we had questions/tags for the really old Might & Magic games, as then we would have might-and-magic-4 as well as heroes-might-magic-4.

Answer (score 8):

The tags all match the official names of the games:

- [Heroes of Might and Magic III](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic_III)
- [Heroes of Might and Magic IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic_IV)
- [Heroes of Might and Magic V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic_V)
- [Might & Magic Heroes VI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Might_&_Magic_Heroes_VI)
- [Might and Magic VII: For Blood and Honor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Might_and_Magic_VII:_For_Blood_and_Honor) (this game isn't part of the Heroes "subseries".)

The important thing is you can google for "heroes 3" and "heroes 6" and "might and magic 7" and still hit our site.

Comment: What a stupidly named series.

Comment: @NickT - Well, it's two separate series. Indeed, Might & Magic Heroes VI's name rearrangement was needlessly confusing.

Comment: Just be glad we've had no questions about the Dark Messiah of Might and Magic games.