# Let's do something to Heroes of Might&Magic tags

Tags: discussion

For now we have the following *Heroes of Might&Magic* series tags, found by "heroes" search queue:

- [might-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-6), 79 questions
- [heroes-might-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-3), 17 questions
- [heroes-might-magic-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-5), 6 questions
- [heroes-might-magic-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-4), 3 questions
- [might-magic-heroes-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-7), 2 questions
- [might-magic-heroes-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-online), 2 questions
  First and second games of the series are not represented yet.

There is a problem with finding those tags if you don't remember exactly how are they formed. If you start typing tags in, it's like 100% that your first word would be "heroes". So the top 6 tags using the word "heroes" pop out: [heroes-of-the-storm](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-of-the-storm), [might-magic-heroes-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-6), [clicker-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clicker-heroes),
 [company-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/company-of-heroes), [fire-emblem-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-emblem-heroes)[heroes-might-magic-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-3). And chances are, you might be Confused for a couple of turns. How should you proceed if not asking a question about one of those two games, sixth and third? Should you try typing "heroes-of"? Shows five completely unrelated tags, as this preposition is omitted due to limited amount of characters available in any tag. Should you follow one of the templates? Which one then?

My proposal is to rename all of the tags to look the same way for clarity purposes, even though sixth and seventh games in the series are originally named a bit differently than previous ones. The template is to be selected.

My second proposal is to create a bunch of "dummy" tags for each game to serve as synonyms that would allow to quickly find those games. For example, if we choose [heroes-might-magic-n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-n) as a template, add something like [might-magic-heroes-n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-n) for each game.

**How should that template look like? Is this problem actually worth solving?**

Comment: I agree to the tag [tag:heroes-might-magic-N] with the synonym [tag:might-magic-heroes-N]. But I don't think we need more tags for a game than we have questions about... two should suffice.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/might-magic-tag-cleanup-request

Comment: These are named after the *official* names of the games. They changed the order of the words at game 6. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic#Games

Comment: It doesn't hurt to have the non-official name as synonym, though.

Comment: @StrixVaria Aye, they are, and that's very misleading for the reasons I have described.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we need to do anything. The current tags follow the [naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic#Games) of the series, however silly the series is for changing that half-way through.

It's minimal overhead for us to change questions to use the correct tag if the user gets it wrong, and it seems that for over 100 questions so far users have mostly figured it out as they've needed to.

Comment: Note that 79 of them are for the sixth game in the series, for sure people have found the tag as it actually pops out when you try to find that game. Another 17 questions were for another game whose title does pop out. Other 4 games share 13 questions, and their tags don't pop out when you type "heroes". It is confusing how should you name a Heroes IV question -- at least at first glance.

Answer (score -1):

I will try two more proposals of tag synonyms for those games: [homm-n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homm-n) (a common acronym for the series) and [heroes-n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-n) (at least Google clearly understands me when I search for "heroes 3" or "heroes 4).

Answer (score -3):

I propose the [heroes-might-magic-n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heroes-might-magic-n) template for all of the games, as most games in the series are named in this way, and [Google Search shows relevant results](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=heroes+might+magic). If two tags of similar nature pop out, I think, that would suffice to understand how to tag the question.

I also propose [might-magic-heroes-n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/might-magic-heroes-n) for all of the games as a synonym, just in case someone tries to use it.