# Tag synonym request: Street Fighter tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-rename-request

As per [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12181/should-we-standardize-our-tag-formatting-regarding-arabic-vs-roman-numerals), the official spelling of the game title should be used in the tags whenever possible, instead of replacing Roman numerals with Arabic numerals.

Requesting that these tags be synonymized:

- [street-fighter-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-5) » [street-fighter-v](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-v)
- [street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-4) » [street-fighter-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-iv)
- [super-street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-4) » [super-street-fighter-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-iv)
- [ultra-street-fighter-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra-street-fighter-4) » [ultra-street-fighter-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra-street-fighter-iv)
- [super-street-fighter-4-3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-4-3d) » [super-street-fighter-iv-3d-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/super-street-fighter-iv-3d-edition) (official title seems to include the word 'edition')
- [street-fighter-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-3) » [street-fighter-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-iii)
- [street-fighter-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-2) » [street-fighter-ii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/street-fighter-ii)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags renamed, synonyms added. Updated tag wikis and excerpts where necessary.